# Do I need to upgrade other circuits if I only plan to change one?

Tags: electrical, circuit-breaker, nec, inspection

(San Francisco, California)

I plan to run a new dedicated circuit for a kitchen appliance, and to get up to code also move the bathroom to its dedicated circuit as well. This is an old house.

The other 10 circuits in the house are not afci protected. I do not plan to touch them. I have a permit for the scope of work I wrote on the application.

When the inspector comes, will they expect me to upgrade the breakers for the other circuits so the whole house is compliant, or just the two that is in my scope of work?

Comment: I would say no, because it is outside the scope of work, i.e. If anything, the AHJ may be miffed because *you didn't pull a permit for that*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ultimate arbiter is your AHJ. Don't be afraid to ask.

My experience in the area (less City proper, more peninsula) is that you won't have to change untouched circuits.